# can we define a variable with multi indices in python?

Tags: python, ampl

I am forced to use python for a part of my code. I coded in ampl my model but now I need to use python to find max of an array.

Here is what I have in AMPL I am wondering can I have kind of the same indices  in python?

I have some information from household and members. For each person in each family I have some utility and I want to find the maximum of that.

I have the parameter U on the set E, for utility

```
             set E ,within F cross N;
              param U{E};
```

So U have 2 indices U[f,i], F shows family and i determine the person.

for example in 4-th family, second person has these utilities:

```
  U[4,2]=5
  U[4,2]=6
  U[4,2]=7
```

and in 3-rd household, first person has these utility

```
  U[3,1]=8
  U[3,1]=9
  U[3,1]=1
```

lets show the max utility by MU, so as an output we have

```
  MU[4,2]=7
  MU[3,1]=9
```

is there any way to find this MU in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dictionary` in `python` to accomplish this. Utility value can be represented as `list` of utility values that belong to one specific family and a person. Family and a person can be represented as `keys` to the dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = defaultdict(list)

df[4, 2] = [5, 6, 7]
df[3, 1] = [8, 9, 1]


for key in df.keys():
    maximum = 0
    for value in df[key]:
        if value > maximum:
            maximum = value
            max_keys = key

    print("(Family, Person) = ", key, "Max of Utility = ", maximum)
```

The output of the code will be

```
(Family, Person) =  (4, 2) Max of Utility =  7
(Family, Person) =  (3, 1) Max of Utility =  9
```